# How to make matrix taking specific columns from Dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, matrix

I have my data set, https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/similarity.csv, is there any way i can make matrix with two specific column and make a matrix of it? For eg:
Count and Topic?

Answer (score 1):

Simply subset the columns of interest, and retrieve the values without the column names using the ".values" attribute.

```py
df = pd.read_html("https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/similarity.csv")[0]
df[["Count","Topic"]].values
```

This returns a 2D numpy array of only the values, then if you need, you can transform into a matrix object like this:

```py
np.matrix(df[["Count","Topic"]].values)
```

Comment: its giving me an array, not the required matrix form :(

Comment: I added an additional line to create the numpy matrix object explicitly. I wasn't sure if you meant matrix more broadly, as a matrix is generally considered an n-dimensional array.